# Ionic 2 : Run a background task

Tags: javascript, android, ios, angular, ionic2

I try to create a background task for my Ionic 2 app. I found this : 
https://ionicframework.com/docs/v2/native/background-mode/

But my IDE doesn't found "backgroundMode" in this line :

```
cordova.plugins.backgroundMode.enable();
```

I have install the plugin.

**Q :** What I have to do to create a function who run when my user doesn't use the app. 
And why I have this error ?

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Cordova plugins only work in devices. You can not use them on browser during development.

If you want to test that plugin, you should run your app with `ionic run android` (or ios) with a device plugged to PC or use an emulator. You can also run `ionic build` and install the debug package on a device.

In development, you can declare cordova variable with `declare var cordova:any;` at begining of script to avoid IDE errors of cordova being an undefined variable.

Comment: Because in build process, Ionic compiler inject cordova.js in your project, making a window.corodva global variable available. But in your IDE there is no cordova.js, so IDE treats it as an undefined variable. You can declare it with `declare var cordova:any;` at begining of script and IDE will stop throwing errors. I update my answer aswell.

Comment: @Ramon-san, could you please tell me how to invoke a method when the app is in background?

Comment: @AnandRaj I do not know. BackgroundMode plugin is for prevent app to be paused by system, not to perform task while in background.